# Old dataset image to excel file

Tags: dataset, document, digitization

I have a series of pictures from some old documents which I want to digitize them and convert them to excel file or other things like this.what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the pictures you are using, you might want to consider looking into a toolkit that supports both scanning in images and OCRing them such as the [LEADTOOLS Document SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document), which has TWAIN and WIA scanning features for scanning in the document images as well as OCR features can be used to convert images into document formats. As I work with the vendor of this toolkit, I can suggest a number of approaches to improve OCR recognition of the text in your images, if this is indeed something that is suitable for you.

But without knowing more details, it is difficult to give a precise answer for what you need. You should provide more information when posting a question like this. For example, describing the input pictures in more details, giving examples on what exactly they are and how do you expect to handle them, as well as elaborating on the outline of the final Excel output you are seeking.